# Perhaps Heroku does not send the request header

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, header, request

There is the following script (*one-request.js*)

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

var options = {
  url: 'https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/anchorage-ak/99501/daily-weather-forecast/346835?day=1', // Anchorage
  headers: {
    'User-Agent':'Web/2.0',
    'Connection':'keep-alive'
  }
};
function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var title = $('div#header-logo > a:first-child > span').text();
    console.log('title:',title); // title: Anchorage Daily Weather
  }
}
request(options, callback);
```

It runs on the home computer (*node one-request.js*) and receives a successful response.

However, when executing the script in Heroku (*heroku run one-request.js*) there is no answer. The same effect is obtained when running the script on the home computer, if the headers are removed in the request. Therefore, I assume that the problem is in the formation of headers in Heroku (also tested the version of `'User-Agent': 'Mozilla / 5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv: 59.0) Gecko / 20100101 Firefox / 59.0.` The same effect).

If the requested address does not require headers (for other sites), the results of the script are equally successful for both the home and Heroku.

How to make a request in the **Heroku**?

Comment: What do you mean by "The same effect is obtained when running the script on the home computer, if the headers are removed in the request"? An HTTP request has headers by definition (at least it must include an HTTP verb and path, e.g. `GET / http/1.1`). Have you tried inspecting the request your application makes, e.g. by logging it?

Comment: When I talked about deleting headers, I meant deleting a code snippet

    headers: {'User-Agent':'Web/2.0','Connection':'keep-alive'}

Yes, of course, some headlines are still transmitted.

Comment: Log of Heroku is of the form
2018-05-14T15:49:18.816424+00:00 heroku[run.3272]: Starting process with command `one-request.js`
2018-05-14T16:00:55.707608+00:00 heroku[run.3272]: Process exited with status 0
2018-05-14T16:00:55.882608+00:00 heroku[run.3272]: State changed from up to complete

Comment: The answer comes in 10 minutes and it's not what was expected.

Comment: When it finally arrives, what is the response?

Comment: No response is received. Apparently, the script stops at timeout.

Comment: After several experiments, I assume that the Accuweather simply blocks the addresses of the Heroku. From the local computer, the data can still be obtained successfully. Blocking was detected for one more hosting, from which the data of Accuweather was successfully requested before. The blockage began on 08-05-2018. This is their right.